# Angular component relative templateUrl

Tags: javascript, angularjs, components, angularjs-components

I'm developing a  modular angular application with I defined I folder path (constant : BASE_PATH : "path/to/folder") in angular-module-1 module. I want to re-used this constant in a angular component located in another module (angular-module-2)of my application. I want to use this constant many time in my project.

```
module.component("relationshipSearch", {
templateUrl: BASE_PATH +'/link/to/other/folder',
```

witch is the best way to define this constant as a global variable visible in all the solution project 
Here is my project structure:

```
project
|-- angular-module-1
|   |-- angular-module-1.js
|   |-- angular-module-1.html
|-- angular-module-2
|   |-- angular-module-2.js
|   |-- angular-module-2.html
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say that create a common module named as `angular-common` where you can place `common` stuff like common `service`, `factory`, `directive`, `constants`, etc.

Then add the constant inside `angular-common`(this would be completely independent and plug-able) module. like below

```
//assuming `angular-common` is already defined
angular.module('angular-common').constant('commmonSetting', {
  'BASE_PATH': '/link/to/other/folder'
})
```

Next, inject this common module in `app`(which is main module, going to be used in `ng-app`/`bootstrap`) like below

```
angular.module('app', ['angular-common', 'ngRoute', ...other dependencies..])
```

When you wanted to use `BASE_PATH` just inject `commmonSetting` dependency in `controller`/`component` wherever you want.

```
app.component('myComponent', {
  templateUrl: function(commmonSetting){
    return commmonSetting.BASE_PATH +'/link/to/other/folder';
  },
  ....
})
```

Comment: Thanks that what I need :)

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, for posting on an old thread with an accepted answer, but I wanted to say that the accepted answer is not minification safe. The minification safe way to write this is:

```
app.component('myComponent', {
  templateUrl: function($injector){
    var commmonSetting = $injector.get('namespace.CommmonSetting');
    return commmonSetting.BASE_PATH +'/link/to/other/folder';
  },
  ....
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a different approach might help. Instead of setting the path why not just look to a file in the same directory.

You could use `require()`, for example:

```
template: require('./template-in-same-dir.html')
```

Note the `template` not `templateUrl`.

Comment: I am asking about the best way to share/re-use constant between the different  module of angular application.

Comment: And yet the title asks about a template url

Comment: I still think my solution to your specific problem is worth considering. By creating multiple modules youve coupled them together for the sake of a string. Seems overkill. But of course theres many ways to bake a cake, it just depends which one is our favourite flavour right! :)

Comment: I have many template in the same folder so i need to define a constant path when using require in TEMPLATEURL i can't use my constant